# Wordpress url image redirect to the homepage

Tags: images, urls

Need help please.

1. I have run into an issue with image pages on my site. All url image, redirect to the homepage. I have double check in YOAST SEO and Redirection and found nothing.

img: teradatariver.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/MSI-GE72VR-Apache-17-Inch-Gaming-Laptop-1024x1021.jpg

But if I open the url post first http://teradatariver.com/327/best-17-inch-laptop/ then the url image it won't redirect to the homepage.

2. Also all image have less indexed in webmaster google.
   [image]

If anyone comes across this and has any idea of how to resolve this issue.

Comment: The URL you posted is invalid, it doesn't open an image for me. Btw, which pages are affected by this? Homepage? Posts? All? Do you mean `Attachment page` by `Image pages`?